# IntellJ IDEA - can't open some dependency jars

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, hadoop-yarn

[image]

as shown in picture above, some jars can be opened, like yarn-client, but some not, like yarn-api & yarn-common, causing errors in editor, warning can't find the class in these jars.

for example, this package is in yarn-api, and can't be resolved by IDEA.

[image]

so why? I can open this jars with winRar, and I can see classes inside.

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. Delete the jars from .m2 directory and reimport the project.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Delete jars and re import, everything goes well, thanks a lot. Please post as answers so I can accept your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jars could be corrupted, you can delete the `.m2` directory in your user home and reimport the project from the `pom.xml` file. Dependencies will be downloaded again.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when something like this goes on you can Invalidate Caches & Restart (See File | Invalidate Caches / Restart ...).

Also reimporting / refreshing helps. Either with maven on command line (deleting your repository (`.m2` folder). Or simply via Maven Projects, and click the Refresh Button.